# A for loop that does the same as if else statement?

Tags: javascript

I have an if else statement, I was wondering if I could change it into a for loop or something similar.

```
if (lastScroll >= 0 && lastScroll < 40) {
    pos = 0;
} else if (lastScroll >= 40 && lastScroll < 80) {
    pos = 1;
} else if (lastScroll >= 80 && lastScroll < 120) {
    pos = 2;
} else if (lastScroll >= 120 && lastScroll < 160) {
    pos = 3;
} else if (lastScroll >= 160 && lastScroll < 200) {
    pos = 4;
} else if (lastScroll > 200) {
    pos = 5;
}
```

I want to change this because there could be over 100 positions. I was thinking about creating a for loop like this:

```
var i = 0;
greater = 0;
less = 40;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (lastScroll >= greater && lastScroll < less) {
        pos = i;
        greater += 40;
        less += 40;
    }

}
```

The if else statement works perfectly but I don't want to create 100 if else statements. This is wrapped in a scroll function.

Comment: @fuyushimoya no, it's just what OP's called the variables, look at the values and it's fine

Comment: Ok, got it. Anyway, it should put a `break;` after `pos = i`, and `greater/less += 40` should move out of that if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's linear you can use division and rounding

```
pos = Math.floor(lastScroll / 40);
if (pos > 5) pos = 5;
```

Comment: Its not clear from OP what happens if pos is less than 0.  I assumed nothing, so left pos unmodified if pos < 0 in my answer.

Comment: @dave as we've got the word _scroll_ appearing, I have assumed that you can't scroll to a negative value. OP may need to consider what to do if this assumption is wrong though (e.g. `if (pos < 0) pos = 0;`)

Comment: Wow! Awesome answer! Thank you very much. I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop.  You can do the following:

```
if( lastScroll > 200 ) {
    pos = 5;
} else if ( lastScroll >= 0 ) {
    pos = Math.floor( lastScroll / 40 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could potentially scrap everything and use

```
pos = int(lastscroll / 40);
```